# Compare 2 date fields - when one date field is null

Tags: oracle

I wanted to select the rows whose date is greater than last processed date.
The last processed date is in hist table.

```
select id
from table1 
where to_date(last_updated_date,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
              > select to_date(nvl(max(last_updated_date),sysdate),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                from table1_hist;
```

This return ORA-01843: not a valid month error.

I had manually inserted row in table1 as TO_DATE('09/26/2019 14:37:49', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') while in table1_hist there are no rows.
But when I query the table using sql developer for table1 I get the value appearing as '26-SEP-19'. last_updated_date is a date field.

I wanted to to get the id's from table1 after the last executed time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`SYSDATE` is a DATE value. Using `TO_DATE()` on a value which is already a `DATE` is useless.

Try

```
where last_updated_date >
       (select MAX(NVL(last_updated_date, SYSDATE)) from table1_hist);
```

Comment: Its returning empty. I guess its because the timestamp of table1.last_update_date is less than sysdate. Can I convert to date and check only for dd/mm/yy, in which case the equality condition will gets satisfied

Comment: I tried

where last_updated_date >=
       (select MAX(NVL(last_updated_date, SYSDATE)) from table1_hist);

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest using an analytical function as following:

```
SELECT
    ID
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            T.ID,
            T.LAST_UPDATED_DATE,
            MAX(TH.LAST_UPDATED_DATE) OVER() AS M_LAST_UPDATED_DATE
        FROM
            TABLE1 T
            JOIN TABLE1_HIST TH ON ( T.ID = TH.ID ) 
            -- i am guessing that this is the join condition or you can use your own conition here
    )
WHERE
    LAST_UPDATED_DATE > COALESCE(M_LAST_UPDATED_DATE, SYSDATE)
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Why is this a solution to his issue?

Comment: This is the other way of achieving the same result.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need any to_date conversion for comparison.

If table1_hist has at least one non-null value, then using

```
select t.id
  from table1 t
 where t.last_updated_date > ( select max(th.last_updated_date) from table1_hist th )
```

is enough, but all those values are null then use a query such as this :

```
select t.id
  from table1 t
 where t.last_updated_date > 
 (select nvl(max(th.last_updated_date),t.last_updated_date-1) from table1_hist th)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9d9c98ea321e26e6c4361973ce12b342)</kbd>